# Place an anchor point between two shapes with regard to their bottom position

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

For some purposes, I want to place an anchor point between two nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.6cm, draw=blue](H1){TEXT};
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.6cm,right=1mm of H1,draw=red](H2) {TEXT};
    \node[fill=orange, below=0mm of H1] at ($(H1)!0.5!(H2)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

I want to place the anchor point such that:

1. it is exactly between two rectangles
2. the y coordinate of its center is exactly the same as the bottom edge of the retangles (or we could say, the same as the south-east point of the blue rectangle)

My code can do the first, but not the second. How to get the y coordinate of either bottom edge of the rectangles, and place the point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to use `($(H1.south east)!0.5!(H2.south west)$)` instead of `($(H1)!0.5!(H2)$)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.6cm, draw=blue](H1){TEXT};
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.6cm,right=1mm of H1,draw=red](H2) {TEXT};
    \node[fill=orange] at ($(H1.south east)!0.5!(H2.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, and I think then `at ($(H1.south)!0.5!(H2.south)$)` works too

Comment: With `($(H1.south)!0.5!(H2.south)$)`, the orange rectangle is not at the desired position if the blue and red rectangles do not have the same width.

Comment: You are right, your solution is more general